# Java AES-256 decrypt with IGE

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm trying to decrypt AES-256 with IGE. But i don't know how use 256 bit key.

in code **key** - *byte[]* with *length* == 32; **IV**.*length* == 32; **BlockSize** == 16

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"));

Xprev = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(IV, 0, BlockSize);
Yprev = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(IV, BlockSize, IV.length);

Decripted = new byte[0];

for (int i = 0; i < Message.length; i += BlockSize) { 
    Y = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Message, i, i+BlockSize); 
    X = XOR(cipher.doFinal(XOR(Y,Xprev)), Yprev);
    Xprev = X;
    Yprev = Y;

    Decripted = sumBytes(Decripted, X);
}
```

Comment: Explain what goes wrong, `InvalidKeyException`?

Comment: seconded.  What's the actual problem?

Comment: The decrypted data is not equal to the presented data

Comment: Could you make it an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? This won't compile for sure.

Comment: The close vote is a bit premature, in my opinion. ftp27, what does sumBytes do? I don't see anything other than the functions E and XOR in IGE...

Comment: OK, so that's probably just append... What test vectors have you tested against?

Comment: What about using jasypt? (http://www.jasypt.org/) It is a simplified API for encryption.

Comment: @mmirwaldt Does that do IGE?

Comment: After swap Xprev with YPrev, all coincided

Comment: sorry for the vote to close btw - was related to my initial misunderstanding.

Comment: Note that I've asked a [question about MDC and IGE on crypto.stackexchange.com](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9395/1172). Note that there are attacks on IGE.

Comment: haha, hello from Challengers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost there. You should swap `Xprev` with `YPrev` in the function and `X` with `Y`. Warning: only tested against a single test vector.

```
public static final byte[] ige(final byte[] key, final byte[] IV,
        final byte[] Message) throws Exception {

    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"));

    final int blocksize = cipher.getBlockSize();

    byte[] xPrev = Arrays.copyOfRange(IV, 0, blocksize);
    byte[] yPrev = Arrays.copyOfRange(IV, blocksize, IV.length);

    byte[] decrypted = new byte[0];

    byte[] y, x;
    for (int i = 0; i < Message.length; i += blocksize) {
        x = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Message, i, i + blocksize);
        y = xor(cipher.doFinal(xor(x, yPrev)), xPrev);
        xPrev = x;
        yPrev = y;

        decrypted = sumBytes(decrypted, y);
    }

    return decrypted;
}
```